# Meaning of admin:/// in a URL

Tags: url

While reading https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/ssd.html#ID6, I noticed this command line instruction:

```
xed admin:///etc/systemd/system/fstrim.timer.d/override.conf
```

I have not seen the specification **admin:///** before and could not find any explanation (the keyword *admin* is apparently an overloaded term).

Would anyone clarify its effect and perhaps point to a source to explain similar conventions, please?

Answer (score 1):

`admin:///` is in this case a
[URI Scheme or Web Protocol](https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/SchemeProtocols.html),
handled by some program installed on the computer.

Wikipedia lists this scheme in its page of
[List of URI schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes):

| Scheme | Purpose | Defined by | General format |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| admin | URL scheme in the GNOME desktop environment to access file(s) with administrative permissions with GUI applications in a safer way, instead of the insecure-considered sudo, gksu & gksudo. | [GNOME Virtual file system](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs/backends) | `admin://<path>/<to>/<file>` example: `gedit admin://etc/default/grub` |

Answer (score 0):

There are application or system-specific protocols that are usually used to allow access to advanced settings in that application or system.

Common ones would be chrome:// (for access to the advanced settings in the Chrome browser, only useful from within a Chrome or Chromium-based browser) ,the admin:// you see, which would be interpreted by whichever application you are working within, // which you precede a phone number with in an HTML file or page in order to make a link that will open a dialer.

These all require that an application supporting that protocol be installed or actively running. Some of these are registered with the system and so will allow the appropriate default application to open when called, and others are only functional within the application itself. Chrome:// for instance only works from inside the Chrome browser, and does not work just anywhere on a system with the Chrome browser installed, while ms-teams:// works anywhere on a system where the Microsoft Teams application is installed.